# Create discount system in php

Tags: php

I was wondering, has anyone ever created a discount system with PHP for ecommerce? i.e: Before discount the price is $100, after the discount the price becomes $85, and the $100 was stroked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that somebody, somewhere has created such a thing.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, what do you want? (>.<) ninja

Comment: sorry, i had to do it...

Comment: Sorry all if my question is unclear.. :) I'm trying to create a discount system for a online store..And i've got the answers from Brian.. :)

Comment: @handoyo: then you should accept Brian's answer.

Answer (score 3):

For changing text to be crossed out, use the `<STRIKE>` tag (Like <strike>this</strike>).  The rest just involves multiplying current price by `1.00 - discount/100.0`, or subtracting `current_price * discount/100.0`.

You can also use css (`text-decoration:line-through;`).  Css is probably a better choice, really.

For example, a 15% discount means taking the price and multiplying by (1-15/100), which means price * 0.85.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian..I've understood..I'll try it... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a short description, but I think you can create a table in your DB with associated to the item ID the discount percentage you want to apply...

Than on the aplication side you can fetch from the DB the original price, print it and after this the new price calculated easily by the original price and the discount percentage.

It's very easy :)